# How to interact with objects inside of a SWT_Window0?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft

I have been having an issue where i need to automate the interaction with objects inside of a SWT_Window0. Within this Window I have a list of objects which need to be clicked and dragged to another part of the screen. I have attached a picture of the SWT_Window0.

The aim I have is to click on "Crosstab" and drag it to the right handside of the screen. The issue I have is UFT only recognises the entire window as one object and does not recognise anything inside it, Crosstab, Spreedsheet etc. And because of this I am having great difficultly getting UFT to click on the "Crosstab" label. Could anyone with more UFT experience potentially share some ideas about how to go about clicking the labels within the SWT_Window0?
I've tried a couple of different ways of trying to click any label within the SWT_Window0 but with no luck. Closest I can get is just using UFT's record which gives:

```
Window("Designer").WinObject("SWT_Window0").Click 64,34
```

But i cannot use this is I do not want to use X,Y coordinates in my test as they are not reliable

```
"Window("Designer").WinObject("SWT_Window0").Click" Just clicks middle of the window.
```

I've also tried other things like
     .Click 2,   
      .Click "Crosstab",   .Press "Crosstab" etc but of no avail

I will also attach the properties of the SWT_Window0

```
"Class Name:=WinObject",
"abs_x:=1925",
"abs_y:=118",
"attached text:=",
"enabled:=True",
"focused:=True",
"hashscroll:=False",
"hasvscroll:=True",
"height:=417",
"hscrollpagesize:=",
"hscrollposition:=",
"hwnd:=69930",
"leftscrollbar:=False",
"maxhscrollpos:=",
"maxvscrollpos:=1142",
"minhscrollpos:=",
"minvscrollpos:=0",
"nativeclass:=SWT_Window0",
"object class:=SWT_Window0",
"regexpwndclass:=SWT_Window0",
"regexpwndtitle:=",
"rightaligned:=False",
"righttoleftlayout:=False",
"righttoleftreading:=False",
"text:=",
"visible:=True",
"vscrollpagesize:=418",
"vscrollposition:=0",
"width:=376",
"window id:=0",
"windowextendedstyle:=1048576",
"windowstyle:=1445003264",
"x:=13",
"y:=126"
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you automating within a RDP session? It looks like UFT hasn't recognised your application. Some pointers: Make sure that your app is opened after UFT has been launched. Ensure that you have the correct add-in. QTP/UFT use hooks to link to an application: look into "**how to setup hooks in QTP/UFT**". You might be more successful with setting the hooks manually if its not automatically hooking into the app

Answer (score 0):

[SWT](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/) is a Java toolkit (Standard Widget Toolkit). 
I suggest you try using UFT's [Java addin](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.03/UFT_Help/Content/Addins_Guide/z_Sxn_AddinJava.htm#).

If that doesn't help, you can try using [Insight](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.03/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/add_IB_TOtoOR_TEST.htm) (image based testing).

Comment: I've tried using UFT's Java Addin and turning off other Addins on start up DirectX, Web etc but no luck, I've also tried Insight recording but no luck either, any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Before going on with other solutions, contact the HPE(Microfocus) support and make sure they do everything possible to recognize these objects as Java Objects. If the cannot help you recognize the Objects as Java Objects then your possibilities are:

**1. Mercury.DeviceReplay**

DragAndDrop Method. You will need to know the coordonates of the source and destination (This requires a static resolution)

**2. Virtual Objects**

Create 2 Virtual Objects on the areas you need. On the source OBject call the Drag method, on the Target the Drop. Restriction is again the resolution.

Comment: I since had to abandon this test as I couldn't get a work around. I did look into both of the options you suggested but unfortunately static resolution wasn't something I could depend on.